# Function returning NaN when it should not

Tags: r

I have defined the following two functions

```
test <- function(t) {   
   return( (0.5*eta^2/theta)*(1-exp(-2*theta*t)) )   
}

test2 <- function(s,t=s) {   
   return( (0.5*eta^2/theta)*exp(-theta*(s+t))*(exp(2*theta*min(s,t)) - 1) )   
}
```

and put

```
> theta=1.2  
> eta=1.8  
> mu=0.2
```

Now the test-function is defined so that `test(t)=test2(t,t)`. The problem is that the following is returned

```
> test2(500)   
[1] NaN    
> test(500)    
[1] 1.35
```

What is wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@tomaskrehlik correctly identified the underflow/overflow problem in the original exponential calculation.  To avoid the problem, you can rewrite it as:

```
test3 <- function(s,t=s) {
   return((0.5*eta^2/theta)*exp(-theta*(s+t)+2*theta*min(s,t)) -
      exp(-theta*(s+t)))
```

In the meantime I am being a little bit baffled about what's going on with that funny `return [expression that evaluates to NaN]` code in the other answer ... ??

Comment: Isn't it something with the fact that R would evaluate the expression until it gets an error and returns the partial result? There is theta(s+t) which actually should return error, because it is not a function.

Comment: That test3 function works perfectly. I have just never encountered such a problem before, but now I will be aware of it.

Answer (score 2):

Probably missing multiplication in the second function, this works for me

```
test <- function(t) {
   return( (0.5*eta^2/theta)*(1-exp(-2*theta*t)) )
}

test2 <- function(s,t=s) {
   return (0.5*eta^2/theta)*exp(-theta(s+t))*(exp(2*theta*min(s,t)) - 1) 
}

theta=1.2
eta=1.8
mu=0.2

test2(500)
test(500)
```

Comment: That is weird. I know they are some *'s in the second function that are not displayed correctly, but this is what I posted: (0.5*eta^2/theta)*exp(-theta*(s+t))*(exp(2*theta*min(s,t)) - 1) which is exactly what you posted.

Comment: Upon further inspection, your function works due to the missing ( ) in the return statement. Why is it, that if you add ( ) around the expression, then you will get NaN?

Comment: When I look at it, given the parameters, the
    exp(-theta*(s+t))
produces 0
    (exp(2*theta*min(s,t)) - 1)
produces Inf Which is probably the reason for NaN

Comment: So my code probably works, because it is somehow wrongly written :-)